# Why laravel is creating garbage name for my model and controller?

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8 and really new to it. I am trying to create a model and controller like this `php artisan make:model Product -mcr` and like this `php artisan make:model Product` and also tried this `php artisan make:controller ProductController` . Yes it creates model and controller BUT the name laravel generated is like this

1. controller => ProdcutControllerProductBrandController.php
2. model => ProductProductBrandController.php ...

I don't have a clue how is this happening .... well it started after I tried creating `php artisan make:model ProductBrand -mcr` and it worked fine.
Can anyone please suggest me how can this be solved ?

Answer (score -1):

The `-r` is indicating that it's to create a resource controller for `ProductBrand`. All model creations after that point will assume that it is tied to that resource and your naming conventions show that.

Have you tried:

1. Closing the terminal and reopening, then run the `make:model` again?
2. You could run `php artisan cache:clear`, or `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: i know that .. but why would it still create same name even if i use php artisan make:model xyz or php artisan make:controller xyzController ???? it generates file named  (model) xyzProductBrand  and  xyzControllerProductBrandController (controller) ??

Comment: So you're saying that no matter what you create next with `make:model` it will always have the `ProductBrand` convention in the name?

Comment: yes you are right...it adds ProductBrandController as suffix  in every model, migrations and controller name i create